# Laravel 4 - Dynamic Routing/Views

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I have a user login system that consists of two steps:

1. User Login

   1. Attempt to bind user to AD (This is the LDAP auth module)
   2. If user can login via AD, check if the user exists in the Users table
   3. If user doesn't exist in Users table, add them - only the "username" and "nice name"

      1. If user is added, they will not belong to any teams and will be notified to contact their manager to continue account setup.
   4. Load user columns into Laravel Session `credentials` - so now we have AD login name, "nice" name (first last), selected team ID, etc.. no passwords because user has authenticated.
2. Team selection - table `userTeams` pivot table.
3. Route user to team dashboard

Right now, I have this route:

```
// This group forces user to be logged in; auth() will check if user has selected a team and ensures the team exists.
Route::group(array('before' => 'auth'), function() {
  // Handle team - URL will be /dashboard -- Team controller based on view_name from `teamUsers` table

  $teamUser = php_sapi_name() == "cli" ? null : @TeamUser::find(Session::get('credentials.team'));
  if(!empty($teamUser)) {
    $team = ucfirst(strtolower($teamUser->teams()->first()->view_name));
    Route::controller('dashboard', 'Team'.$team.'Controller');
  }

  // Handle index
  Route::controller('/', 'IndexController');
});
```

However, I don't feel this is a very elegant solution - mostly because I cannot do reverse routing doing this method.

Any tips or suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would personally choose to do this logic in it's own filter rather than the Route Group closure, since what you are doing is simply 'filtering' users to different routes depending on variables (same thing an Auth filter does).

**update**

```
Route::filter('whatever', function()
{
  $teamUser = php_sapi_name() == "cli" ? null : @TeamUser::find(Session::get('credentials.team'));

  if ( empty($teamUser) )
    Redirect::route('IndexController');
});

Route::group(array('before' => 'auth|whatever', function()
{
  Route::controller('someController');
  Route::controller('/', 'IndexController');
}));
```

Comment: Could you provide an example?

Comment: I see what you mean.. however, I'm still unable to get reverse routes from this. Any thoughts?

Comment: PS: Route::controller('someController') -- 'someController' would be the dynamic name, such as `'Team'.$team.'Controller'`